# Recursively find all files that match a certain pattern

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I need to find (or more specifically, count) all files that match this pattern:

*/foo/*.doc

Where the first wildcard asterisk includes a variable number of subdirectories.

Comment: Does it have to be bash? zsh can do this using the syntax `ls **/foo/*.doc`.

Comment: Alastair, thanks for the suggestion. I was not aware of zsh and its double-asterisk syntax. Interestingly, it appears the resulting expanded argument list is too long for ls (approx. 6000 filenames) and gives an error.

Comment: Bash v4 also supports the `**` recursive glob.

Comment: An internal command like `echo` avoids the `ARG_MAX` problem (argument list too long). [You should not be using `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee Bash v4 supports `**` recursive glob, but you must first `shopt -s globstar`. See https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With gnu find you can use regex, which (unlike `-name`) match the entire path:

```
find . -regex '.*/foo/[^/]*.doc'
```

To just count the number of files:

```
find . -regex '.*/foo/[^/]*.doc' -printf '%i\n' | wc -l
```

(The `%i` format code causes `find` to print the inode number instead of the filename; unlike the filename, the inode number is guaranteed to not have characters like a newline, so counting is more reliable. Thanks to @tripleee for the suggestion.)

I don't know if that will work on OSX, though.

Comment: Append "| wc -l" to the end of this and it's perfect.

Comment: What about just `-printf '0\n'`? We don't really need the inode at all.

Answer (score 14):

how about:

`find BASE_OF_SEARCH/*/foo -name \*.doc -type f | wc -l`

What this is doing:

- start at directory BASE_OF_SEARCH/
- look in all directories that have a directory foo
- look for files named like *.doc
- count the lines of the result (one per file)

The benefit of this method:

- not recursive nor iterative (no loops)
- it's easy to read, and if you include it in a script it's fairly easy to decipher (regex sometimes is not).

UPDATE: you want variable depth?  ok:

`find BASE_OF_SEARCH -name \*.doc -type f | grep foo | wc -l`

- start at directory BASE_OF_SEARCH
- look for files named like *.doc
- only show the lines of this result that include "foo"
- count the lines of the result (one per file)

Optionally, you could filter out results that have "foo" in the filename, because this will show those too.

Comment: This works except for the fact that it does not work with a variable subdirectory depth between BASE_OF_SEARCH and foo. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough with that specification. It's close enough though that I was able to accomplish the task I set out to do, so an upvote and thank you.

Comment: You should emphasize that it is not recursive. However, this is often not needed. Then it is a simpe and nice solution. Though it could have performance issues - don't know.

Comment: I've added a feature for your requests

Answer (score 13):

Based on the answers on this page on other pages I managed to put together the following, where a search is performed in the current folder and all others under it for all files that have the extension *pdf*, followed by a filtering for those that contain *test_text* on their title.

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | grep test_text | wc -l
```

Comment: I managed to find the original post with the answer containing all the info
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/why-is-my-find-not-recursive

Comment: The `grep` is overkill in this answer. The following will give you the same result:

`find . -name "*test_text*.pdf" | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but try:

```
find . -type d -name foo -print | while read d; do echo "$d/*.doc" ; done | wc -l
```

find all the "foo" directories (at varying depths) (this ignores symlinks, if that's part of the problem you can add them); use shell globbing to find all the ".doc" files, then count them.

Comment: The `while` loop is fully redundant and somewhat error-prone. Also, the wildcard will not be expanded because it is quoted. Just pipe `find -print` to `wc -l`. However, this will still give the wrong count if a file name contains a newline.